# How to perform a search using characters "+ - =" .etc

Tags: php, search, search-engine, operation

I am am trying to remember the meaning of `+=` in the following:

```
$total += cumumalitive_norm($x, $mean, $sd);
```

I know this is simple just not 100% sure if I'm right. I am presuming it means

```
$total = $total + cumumalitive_norm($x, $mean, $sd);
```

After trying to use Google to search for an answer then this website, I have released
that the characters "+ - =" .etc don't respond well in a search engine.

Is there a hack I can do to return better results?
I was googling "php +=".

Regards

Comment: Well I just thought it might be a useful question to others. Also I wanted to clear up my presumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Google search you could type out plus and equals. Example: php plus equals.

And yes that is what the += means, but I only believe it works for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Thats right `+=` is a short form. Search engines ignore almost any special char and short words. If you know what you are searching for that isn't a big problem. You would like to know more about operators in PHP? Google it or [go directly to the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php).